# Why is startService() and bindService() only working when used in the activities' onStart() method?

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-service-binding

Initially, I attempted to start and bind my services using a function in my MainActivity like so:

```
public void startTimerService(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimerService.class);
    startService(intent);

    ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "onServiceConnected");
            TimerService.LocalBinder binder = (TimerService.LocalBinder) iBinder;
            timerService = binder.getService();
            boundToTimer = true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            boundToTimer = false;
            Log.d("MainActivity", "onServiceDisconnected");
        }
    };
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, TimerService.class);

    bindService(intent2, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    timerService.startTimer();
}
```

This gave me a nullPointerException when I tried to access `timerService.startTimer();` However, when I moved the code to the `onStart()` method as such:

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimerService.class);
    startService(intent);

    ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "onServiceConnected");
            TimerService.LocalBinder binder = (TimerService.LocalBinder) iBinder;
            timerService = binder.getService();
            boundToTimer = true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            boundToTimer = false;
            Log.d("MainActivity", "onServiceDisconnected");
        }
    };
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, TimerService.class);

    bindService(intent2, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

and put only the `timerService.startTimer();` method call in the `startTimerService()` method, everything works perfectly. The only problem is that I have no idea why this is case, perhaps someone can enlighten me.

Comment: Timerservice is still null. It is set in the callback, which probably has not yet been called.

Comment: But why would the callback have been called in the latter situation, but not the former?

Comment: `bindService` is an async call, you have to wait for `onServiceConnected` to be called before you start doing anything with the service